# How do I install the col command?

Tags: package-management

I've tried installing `col` on Ubuntu Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install col
```

but I get the error:

```
E: Couldn't find package col
```

What's the best way to install `col` on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

The col command is provided by the bsdmainutils package, so:

```
sudo apt-get install bsdmainutils
```

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/col.1.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/col.1.html

Comment: In the future, you can install **apt-file** to find out what package provides a given file.

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get install bsdutils` it says **bsdutils is already the newest version** but I still can't use the `col` command. Are you sure it's part of this package?

Comment: @sferik Used to be bsdutils. Evidently it changed packages to bsdmainutils.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have it (and `column` seems to have more options than `col`, both are available), you can install it with `apt` from the `bsdextrautils` package (formerly `bsdmainutils` and `bsdutils` prior to that).

---

I found out the package name thanks to the `apt-file` package, thus:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update && sudo apt-file search column | grep "/usr/bin/col"
```